# Dynamic title and sliders using manipulate package in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Using the package manipulate in Rstudio, I'm trying to create a scatterplot in which I can select among several data frames using a picker and then using sliders I control the columns I'd like to plot for each axis. For example, using these two datasets: mtcars and iris.

```
library(manipulate)  
manipulate(  
 plot(dataset[, xaxis] ~ dataset[, yaxis], 
   dataset, 
   xlab = colnames(dataset)[xaxis],
   ylab = colnames(dataset)[yaxis], 
   main = title),
   xaxis = slider(1, 10), 
   yaxis = slider(1, 10), 
   dataset = picker("mtcars" = mtcars, "iris" = iris),
   title = picker("mtcars", "iris")
   )
```

It works ok, however, I'm struggling with two questions:

1. How to change dynamically the title of the plot based on the selected dataset (mtcars or iris) instead of manually using another picker as I do in the example above. I'm unable to get the name of the selected data frame and pass it as a character title.
2. How can I determine dynamically the max argument of the sliders, instead of hardcoding in the sliders from 1 to 10. For example mtcars has 11 columns and iris 5. Or better still, select the columns for each axis by name. I've tried many different ways but I think the problem is that I can't pass variables used in a control (dataset) to others (sliders). For example, this generates an error:

   xaxis = slider(1,as.numeric(dim(dataset)[2]))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a different approach, after reading an example included in *Learning RStudio for R Statistical Computing* by Mark P. J. Van der Loo. I wrote a function that solves my problems:

```
library(manipulate)
scatterplot <- function(dataset){
  vars <- as.list(names(dataset))
  name <- sys.call()[[2]]
manipulate(
  plot(dataset[, xaxis] ~ dataset[, yaxis], 
       xlab = colnames(dataset)[xaxis],
       ylab = colnames(dataset)[yaxis], 
       main = as.character(name)),   
  xaxis = slider(1, as.numeric(dim(dataset)[2]), initial = 1), 
  yaxis = slider(1, as.numeric(dim(dataset)[2]), initial = 2)  
  )
}
scatterplot(mtcars)
```